# fscanf fails on last row of input (negative values only?)

Tags: c, input

I wrote a function to parse a file input. The file includes a row of floating point numbers, and the function is supposed to put them into a cluster of vectors.

The last row of the file will sometimes be in the the result and sometimes it will not. fscanf return 1, and the input of this last row will fail. I added an example to reproduce the issue.

The source code:

```
typedef struct vectors { 
        double** vecs; 
        int n; /* number of vectors */
} vectors;

vectors* parseInput(char* file_name, int dim) {
    float coordinate;
    char c;
    double *vec;
    int i=0, ind=0, j=0, debug;
    FILE* input;
    vectors* datapoints;
    double** vex = (double**) calloc (1000*dim, sizeof (double*)); 
    assert(vecs != NULL);
    datapoints = (vectors*)malloc(sizeof(vectors));
    assert(datapoints != NULL);
    input = fopen(file_name, "r");
    assert(input != NULL);
 
    while (1) { /* loop until EOF */
        debug= fscanf(input, "%f%c", &coordinate, &c);
        printf("%d%s", debug, "\n");
        if(debug!=2)
        {
            printf("%s%d%s","fscanf value: ",debug,"\n"); // if in last row (that has negative values), will print 1
            printf("value: ");
            printf("%lf",coordinate);
            printf(" char: ");
            printf("%c", c);
            break;
        }
         if (j == 0)
        {
            vec = (double *)calloc(dim, sizeof(double));
            assert(vec != NULL);
        }
        if(c!='\n' && coordinate!='\n')
        {
        vec[j] = coordinate;
        j++;
        }
        if (j == dim)
        {
            print_vec(vec, dim);
            vecs[i] = vec;
            i++;
            j = 0;
        }
    }
    vecs = (double**)realloc(vecs, i*sizeof(double*));
    assert(vecs != NULL);
    datapoints->vecs = vecs;
    datapoints->n = i;
    fclose(input);
    return datapoints;
}
```

On the input (as a txt file)

-5.05604381,11.01146785 
-6.40861975,-7.96222506 
5.69419195,9.60601354 
6.60569313,9.39602582 
-6.771797,-5.72717303 
-4.49752324,8.39891449 
-4.98452388,9.0760693 
4.42351449,8.81860878 
-7.59529807,-7.21054155 
**-4.19783158,8.37108438**

The output will be:

-5.0560,11.0115 
-6.4086,-7.9622 
5.6942,9.6060 
6.6057,9.3960 
-6.7718,-5.7272  
-4.4975,8.3989 
-4.9845,9.0761 
4.4235,8.8186  
-7.5953,-7.2105 
**no last line **

The main function I used:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    int i;
    int k = atoi(argv[1]);
    int dim = get_dim_from_file(argv[3]); // works fine
    vectors* datapoints = parseInput (argv[3], dim); //the function in discussion
    double** vecs = datapoints->vecs;
    int n = datapoints->n;
    const char* goal = argv[2];
    if(!strcmp(goal, "parse"))
    {
        printf("%s%d%s","\n", datapoints->n,"\n" );
        print_matrix(datapoints->vecs, datapoints->n, dim);
    }

}

void print_matrix(double** A, int n, int k) {
    int row, col;
    for (row = 0; row < n; row++) {
        for (col = 0; col < k-1; col++) {
            if ((A[row][col] < 0) && (A[row][col] > -0.00005)) {
                A[row][col] = 0;
            }
            printf("%.4f%s", A[row][col], ",");
        }
        if ((A[row][k-1] < 0) && (A[row][k-1] > -0.00005)) {
            A[row][k-1] = 0;
        }
        printf("%.4f%s", A[row][k-1], " \n");
    }
}
```

If anyone has an idea how to fix this, it could be great!

Thanks!

Comment: Read lines with `fgets` then parse with `strtok` / `strtod`.

Answer (score 1):

Some text files do *not* have a newline at the end of the *last* line.

A well formed file:

```
-5.05604381,11.01146785\n
-6.40861975,-7.96222506\n
...
-4.19783158,8.37108438\n
```

A not so well formed [but *still* valid] file:

```
-5.05604381,11.01146785\n
-6.40861975,-7.96222506\n
...
-4.19783158,8.37108438
```

Your `fscanf` will handle the first file but *not* the second.

---

Also, in `fscanf`, `"%f"` is for a `float`, but [if] you have a `double`, you want `"%lf"`.

As it is, you're scanning into `coordinate` which is a `float` but your vector is `double`, so you're [potentially] losing precision at the outset. Better to scan directly into the vector element.

---

Note: for brevity/clarity, I'm omitting the dynamic array allocation.

*If* you have a *fixed* number of numbers per line, you can do:

```
int count;
double vec[1000];

while (1) {
    if (fscanf(input,"%lf,%lf",&vec[count + 0],&vec[count + 1]) != 2)
        break;
    count += 2;
}
```

This will work for *either* case and is more usual/idiomatic.

---

*If* you have a *variable* count per line, better to use `fgets` and `strtod`.

Personally, I prefer this because it gives better error detection/control.

```
int count;
double vec[1000];
char buf[100];

while (1) {
    char *cp = fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),input);
    if (cp == NULL)
        break;

    while (1) {
        vec[count++] = strtod(cp,&cp);

        // no newline
        if (*cp == 0)
            break;

        // has a newline
        if (*cp == '\n')
            break;

        // syntax error
        if (*cp++ != ',')
            break;
    }
}
```